# Issue when Invisible Sale Order line Description Field

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Currently, I'm working on odoo version 12.0.

I'm facing the issue, When I invisible sale order line Description field from Tree view at that time it also invisible the section text & Note Text.

Code for invisible sale order line Description field:

```
<xpath  expr="//page[@name='order_lines']//tree/field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>     ​ 
​</xpath>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First look if the view file is added in manifest

Comment: @Explorer Doesn't get issue with invisible sale order line Description field. But it raised issue when invisible Description(name) field not display section note text.

Comment: @AvaniSomaiya The Section Text and Note Text is depend on the field 'Description'. So if you hide this field other two options will not work.It will also  get hidden.

Comment: @AjmalJK Yes, this is an actual issue. I need to hidden 'Description' field and display the Section Text and Note Text.

Comment: @AvaniSomaiya It is note a issue, we can't hide it simply by xpathing, we have to customize according to this.

Comment: @AvaniSomaiya Section Text and Note Text is stored in description field actually.Thats why the issue.

Comment: @AjmalJK Yes, I know that Section Text and Note Text is stored in the description field. But how can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Technically Description, section text and note text is same field='name' in sale.order.line at client-side UI tweak based on field `display_type` 
you should try attrs invisible based on display_type instead of invisible=1

ref:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L1223

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when I invisible Description field according to display_type field at that time it also displays "Description" in sale order tree view header line.
Have you any solution for remove from the header ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
<record id="view_order_form_inherit_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.custom</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
</record>
```